# Where can I find a list of terminal ANSI codes sent by Ctrl-key sequences?

Tags: terminal, xterm

I am writing some behavioural tests for code that interacts with a terminal and I need to assert behaviour on the sequence `C-p C-q` (ctrl-p ctrl-q). In order to do this, I need to write the raw characters to the PTY. I have a small mapping at the moment for things like `C-d => 0x04, C-h => 0x08`.

Is there somewhere I can get a basic mapping of human readable control sequences, mapped to raw byte sequences for xterm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the ASCII value of the character (e.g., for `^H`, take 72), and subtract 64. Thus, `^H` is 8.

This works for any control character. Using it, you can discover that, for example, `^@` is the NUL character and `^[` is ESC.

Comment: That's a really simple calculation, thanks. I had no idea it was that simple. I'd been Googling for ages.

Comment: Actually not *subtract*, but masking off a bit (which is more cumbersome to state).  Control-modifier applied to a control character does not subtract, for instance.